# Change view when tableview cell is pressed?

Tags: iphone, uitableview

i need help. When my tableView's cell is selected, i want the cell to go to a page of its own, i don't want every cell to go to the same page. I tried using :

```
FirstFolderViewController * first = [[FirstFolderViewController alloc]init];
first.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
[first presentModalViewController:first animated:YES];
[first release];
```

i added this to the didSelectRowAtIndexPath: method. but it won't work any idea?? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, albertamg's answer points out an important concept; the `presentModalViewController` should be called on `self`.

Second, it sounds like you need to have something unique happen in each subsequent view that you present, presumably based on data that creates your table cell. One way to do this is to set a `@property` on your `FirstFolderViewController`, just before you present it, and then when it's `viewWillAppear` function, is called, you can act on that value.

For example,

```
FirstFolderViewController * first = [[FirstFolderViewController alloc]init];
first.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;

first.folderNumber = indexPath.row; // Added

[self presentModalViewController:first animated:YES];
[first release];
```

...assuming you're calling this inside your `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` method, and you've set up a property called `folderNumber` inside your `FirstFolderViewController`.

Comment: sure man good luck! if you haven't already, the stanford ios lectures (free on itunes) are a giant help.