# How can I have each row of a UITableView direct the user to a new page?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Change view when tableview cell is pressed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6864681/change-view-when-tableview-cell-is-pressed)

I have a UITableView with several rows, and I'd like to have it so that tapping on each row would take you to a different view.  How can I do this?

Comment: Didn't you just ask this same question yesterday? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6864681/change-view-when-tableview-cell-is-pressed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have the user id stored in the same array as your TableView data you could well use indexPath to access this information and pass it off to another control like a UIViewController. eg.

```
NSDictionary *selectedUser = [MyTableViewDataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
MyUserViewController *userVController = [[MyUserViewController alloc] initWithUser:selectedUser];
```

you could then push this viewcontroller onto the stack

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:userVController animated:YES];
[userViewController release];
```

obviously this is a pseudo example but should help you.

Tim

Answer (score 0):

Create a new project from the Navigation-based application template and XCode will generate you the example code.